# Time Capsule Firmware upgrade from 7.5.2 to 7.6 fails

Tags: time-capsule

I have an Apple Time Capsule 802.11n (3rd Gen) running firmware 7.5.2.

The amber light was blinking, and AirPort Utility shows that I need to do a firmware upgrade to 7.6.

However, when I try to do so, it fails with "error occurred".[image: "An error occurred while updating the firmware"]

Not a lot to go on, and I've checked the Apple support site. The readme for the update says I should use AirPort Utility 5.5.3., which is the version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

The time capsule probably needed a full power down and reboot.

REASON:

I had given up on fixing the problem in-house, so I made a Genius Bar appointment, and went to the Apple Store. When I got there, they powered up my unit, and the light went green. The utility confirmed the new firmware was installed.

So, based on that experience, my assumption is that the new firmware took effect on reboot. The error could have been cosmetic, or a reboot failure, or some other transient exception (the time capsule was supposed to reboot, and upgrade attempts against a patched unit return an error).

Anyhow, why didn't I just reboot as part of standard troubleshooting? Because the Apple site never suggested that was the solution to any problem, so I didn't try it.